# non-conforming SQL syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working with vendor software that enables me to create reports from the data in their modern Oracle database (18c).  One of the reports is having trouble returning large amounts of data.  The vendor has informed me that my SQL is "non-conforming".  They say that SQL like this...

```
select a.Name
, a.Descr

from tblA a
  inner join tblB b on b.aID = a.aID
  inner join tblC c on c.bID = b.bID

where sysdate between c.StartDate and c.EndDate
  and c.Name in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

...is wrong, and this...

```
select a.Name
, a.Descr

from tblA a
, tblB b

where b.aID = a.aID
  and b.bID in (
    select c.bID
    from tblC c
    where sysdate between c.StartDate and c.EndDate
      and c.Name in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
  )
```

...is correct.

This is a dramatically boiled down example.  The original query is huge, but this is basically the difference I am being told is causing problems.

I'm confused because I'm not seeing any meaningful difference.

1. Could these queries produce different results?
2. Could the `INNER JOIN` cause duplication that the "in (subquery)" syntax avoids?
3. How does using the subquery add any value?  Could it be faster?
4. Wasn't the "comma" style join deprecated about 2 decades ago?

Comment: Comma joins are over 30+ years old and should not be used. Your query is technically fine but unknown what table `sysdate` is from - *always* qualify columns. As to could it be faster, produce different results... you can test it, we can't.

Comment: @Stu: `SYSDATE` is an Oracle function that returns the current datetime.

Comment: Lol maybe you can spot I'm not familiar with Oracle :)

Comment: @Stu `SYSDATE` is like `GETDATE()` in `SQL Server`

Comment: My standard answer: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: For example, Oracle uses comma-style joins for Oracle EBS in all releases, don't know why. They deploy all new views with this same stone age joins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I suppose that `b.aID = b.aID` is a typo and should be `b.aID = a.aID`.

Then, it is weird to see they want you to use a comma join (`from tblA a, tblB b`), like was done in the 1980s. This is an out-dated syntax that should not be used nowadays.

But yes, the original query may lead to duplicate result rows. If you only want to select data from tblA, then only select from tblA and put the criteria in the `WHERE` clause. I suppose that this is what they are trying to do by putting tblC into an `IN` clause. A good idea, which should look something like this:

```
SELECT a.name, a.descr
FROM tbla a
WHERE a.aid IN 
(
  SELECT b.aid
  FROM tblb b 
  INNER JOIN tblc c ON c.bid = b.bid
  WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN c.startdate AND c.enddate
  AND c.name IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
);
```

Answering your questions:

1. Could these queries produce different results? Yes.
2. Could the INNER JOIN cause duplication that the "in (subquery)" syntax avoids? Yes.
3. How does using the subquery add any value? Could it be faster? Yes, faster and not producing duplicates.
4. Wasn't the "comma" style join deprecated about 2 decades ago? Even three decades ago, actually, but Oracle was ten years late to adopt the syntax. So, yes.

The line

```
WHERE SYSDATE BETWEEN c.startdate AND c.enddate
```

looks a bit suspicious by the way. startdate and enddate are probably dates, while `SYSDATE` also contains a time. So we want SYSDATE to be in a date range, but depending on whether enddate is inclusive or exclusive, this should be

```
WHERE c.startdate <= SYSDATE AND c.enddate > SYSDATE
```

or

```
WHERE c.startdate <= SYSDATE AND c.enddate > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

in order not to allow the following midnight to get included.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo.  I fixed it in both queries.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll take a look at the query outputs under the conditions generating the complaint to see if duplication could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe the vendor wasn't trying to make the Oracle native vs. ANSI join syntax the issue. I think the rewrite they suggested shows that your join to `tblC` was increasing your row count improperly (if `c.bid` is not unique within `tblC` for a given date), and suggested the subquery so that it doesn't multiply your rows. There are other ways to do that, but their suggestion is fine. In other words, to your question:

> Could the INNER JOIN cause duplication that the "in (subquery)" syntax
> avoids?

Yes. That's probably the whole point. Or it could be they are trying to tune your query and offered what they think would be faster. It may or may not be, but again the subquery is the point, not the join syntax.

Speaking of the native Oracle join syntax, contrary to what most others on this forum keep saying, there's nothing wrong with it. It has never been deprecated and there's a ton of it out there still in use. It's largely a matter of style and personal usage. That's probably what the vendor was most familiar with, and probably not what they are saying you should change. Choose whichever syntax you prefer and go with it.

Comment: Right answer.  2 hours later than the other right answer.  I hear what you're saying about the comma-style joins.  Personally, I find them nearly impossible to maintain.  Plus, I have seen the same line duplicated (dozens of lines apart) in the `WHERE` clause in this vendor's code.  That wouldn't happen if the join logic was in the `FROM` statement where it's easier to see the mistake.  And they do use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, they just refuse to use `INNER JOIN`.  Very confusing to read and maintain.